# What exactly does display:block; do to an element?

Tags: css

What are the exact specs of display:block? I know quite a few of the specific things applying this to an element will do but I would like to hear them all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Quote from W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)

> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin' properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block boxes in a block formatting context collapse.
>
> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a box's content area may shrink due to the floats).

Answer (score 4):

Autistic Cuckoo's article about display properties and their differences ([part 1](http://web.archive.org/web/20090426004947/http://www.autisticcuckoo.net/archive.php?id=2005/01/11/block-vs-inline-1), [part 2](http://web.archive.org/web/20090422055124/http://www.autisticcuckoo.net/archive.php?id=2005/01/12/block-vs-inline-2), [part 3](http://web.archive.org/web/20090413025724/http://www.autisticcuckoo.net/archive.php?id=2005/01/13/block-vs-inline-3)) is also a recommended read.

Comment: I converted the links here to their archive.org form, since the original site seems to be offline.